# Django3 - Issue populating Navbar item SQlite DB data using Context Processors

Tags: python, django, routes

I have a record label website im building and I want to populate a navbar dropdown list with artists from the Artst object Artist.objects.all().

I have it working in one app "music" but only when I append "/artistlist/" onto the end. Any other URL doesnt populate the list.

I want the list to always be there as its a navbar item. At the moment I am trying to get a context_processors.py working.
[youtube tutorial im following for the exactsame issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eWLaL2g1bo)

I could use some help as I'm clearly doing something stupid, or overlooked something basic. On all other urls it triggers the else I added "We currently dont have any artists yet..".

Hope it makes sense to someone. Any help is greatly appreciated.

base.html

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
    <div class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        {% if all_artists %}
        <ul>
            {% for artist in all_artists %}
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <a href="{% url 'music:artist' artist.id %}">
                        <img src="{{ artist.artist_logo.url }}" style="width: 100px"><br>
                        {{ artist.artist_name }}<br>
                        {{ artist.artist_url }}<br>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% else %}
            <h3>We currently dont have any artists yet..</h3>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

main urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # include urls from the music app
    path('music/', include('music.urls', namespace='music')),
    # path('', include('music.urls', namespace='home')),
    path('', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
    # path('single', include('blog.urls', namespace='single')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

music/models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Artist(models.Model):
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
    artist_logo = models.FileField()
    artist_url = models.URLField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist_name

class Release(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    release_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    release_cover = models.FileField()
    release_duration = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.release_title

class Track(models.Model):
    release = models.ForeignKey(Release, default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    track_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    track_version = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    track_genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    track_duration = models.IntegerField()
    track_number = models.SmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["track_number"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.track_title

app_name = 'music'
```

music/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from . import views
# from blog.views import newsfeed, single

urlpatterns = [
    # no info past music return index EG /music/
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    # re_path(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

    # Releases
    # albums/releases
    re_path(r'^release/$', views.ReleaseView.as_view(), name='release'),
    # looking for music page with album id afterwards /music/1
    re_path(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),

    # Artists
    re_path(r'^artistlist.html$', views.ArtistListView.as_view(), name='artistlist'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ArtistView.as_view(), name="artist"),

    # Register
    # register url
    re_path(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name="register"),
]

# defined the app name in case the same fields are used in other apps
app_name = 'music'
```

music/context_processors.py

```
from .models import Artist

def all_artists(request):
    artist = Artist.objects.all()
    return {'artist':artist}
```

I found this vieo which is exactly the same issue, and tried adjusting the context processor to te above, and also tried just:

```
from music.models import Artist:
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'music.context_processors.all_artists',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: If it should be available on every single page then you should consider using a context processor

Comment: can you show us the urls.py in the musics app?

Comment: I have tried to use the coontext processors but it doesnt appear to be working. I found a great video attached above showing how to do it, but I just doesnt seem to work. Instead it just seems to be still working on the one page, and if I change the music/views.py for ArtistListView then it crashes when I remove the context_object_name = 'all_artists' or model = Artist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only thing you want to do is change the return key value to all_artists because you fetch all data through all_artists key in your base.html but according to your code there is not any all_artists found do change in the last line in context_processor.py and you are good to go

music/context_processors.py

```
from .models import Artist

def all_artists(request):
    artist = Artist.objects.all()
    return {'all_artists':artist}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Krishan,

that did the trick alright. Can you clarify that the return all_artists:artist  just returns each artist gathered by the function all_artists? Apologies I havent been near Django or Python for a while.

I need to wait 9 hours to send you the bounty by the way..

Comment: It doesnt matter what your function name is but you have to load same function in your settings.py in context processor list and and when you return any query you have to put any key just like return {'all_artisan: query_set} so you can also change the name all_artisan but you have to specify the same name in the template/html file to get that data hope you will get your answer from this